# A verb for when we do something that make others lose trust in us

Tags: single-word-requests

> They are always honest with each other because they don't like to ----- mutual trust.

*Ruin, endanger, risk,* and *imperil* are a couple of suggestions that I have seen  used on the Internet. But I am looking for the most idiomatic verb for sentences such as the above.

Comment: @Dan Done. Actually it was just a letter.

Answer (score 2):

**Undermine** is suitable in this case.

Mutual trust is wording that is used to describe established relationships where trust has built up over a period of time.

Therefore, anything which poses a risk to that trust is something that undermines the foundations of that firmly established relationship.

The word undermine is used on Wikipedia in relation to the legal term 'Mutual Trust and Confidence' expressed in UK law.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_trust_and_confidence)

Answer (score 2):

"Betray" is probably the best general verb.

Its main usage is to mean to break faith or agreement.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/betray

Answer (score -1):

> **Perfidy**
>   
>   2. An act or instance of disloyalty

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfidy

Verbify: commit perfidy or commit a perfidious act.